# Setting name of UIImage

Tags: swift, uiimage, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiimagepngrepresentation

I am building an app that allows the user to resize an uploaded image that will then present the `UIActivityViewController` to allow them to AirDrop or email the files to the Mac.

I would like to be able to rename the exported image to contain the new size when it is sent back to the Mac. Is this possible and if so, how should I go about it?

Thank you

Comment: What code do you have so far? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm interested on if there's an answer. iOS - even iOS 11 - tries to *not* let a user think of images (or anything else) as a file. I know you can save things and do some manipulation, but that's a *save*, not using AirDrop or an email attachment. In my apps I don't worry about this, as (1) not many other apps - including Apple's - seem to care about file naming until afterwards, and (2) the metadata can usually provide enough for image libraries.